# Ply - Catching lexical errors

Tags: python, compiler-construction, scanning, ply, lexical

I 'm having a hard time to figure out if there is a mistake with my code or whether it is that Ply can't catch some lexical errors.
I am writing a small compiler in Python for my compilers' class at university, I've wrote some of the lexical analyzer using the lib Ply. In the scanning part I have the following rules for identifiers and numbers:

```
# Rule for identificator
def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
    return t

# Regular expression rules for simple tokens
t_NUMBER  = r'\d+'
```

The number rule is just temporary, I am going to add something more specific to deal with floating point, and integer numbers.
The issue is that when testing the scanning if I type something like 012abc it returns to me :

LexToken(NUMBER,'123',1,0)
LexToken(ID,'abc',1,3)

shouldn't it throw an error message instead?

Below is the full code.

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc


# Reserved words
reserved = {
    'if' : 'IF',
    'else' : 'ELSE',
    'while' : 'WHILE',
    'for' : 'FOR',
    'switch' : 'SWITCH',
    'case' : 'CASE',
    'class' : 'CLASS',
    'define' : 'DEFINE',
    'int' : 'INT',
    'float' : 'FLOAT',
    'string' : 'STRING',
    'void' : 'VOID',
    'equal' : 'EQUAL',
    'and' : 'AND',
    'or' : 'OR',
    'not' : 'NOT',
    'do' : 'DO',
}

# The tokens declaration is made here.
tokens = [

    # Literals (identifier, integer constant, float constant, string constant,
    # char const)
    # TODO add constants' Types
    'ID',
    'NUMBER',

    # Operators +,-,*,/,%
    'PLUS',
    'MINUS',
    'TIMES',
    'DIVIDE',
    'MOD',

    # Logical Operators
    'LESS_THAN',
    'LESS_EQUAL',
    'GREATER_THAN',
    'GREATER_EQUAL',
    'NOT_EQUAL',

    # Delimeters such as (),{},[],:
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'LBRACE',
    'RBRACE',
    'COLON',

    #Assignment Operators
    'EQUALS'

] 

tokens +=  list(reserved.values())

# Regular expression rules for simple tokens
t_NUMBER  = r'\d+'

# Operators
t_PLUS    = r'\+'
t_MINUS   = r'-'
t_TIMES   = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE  = r'/'
t_MOD     = r'\%'

# Logical Operators
t_LESS_THAN     = r'<'
t_LESS_EQUAL    = r'<=' 
t_GREATER_THAN  = r'>'
t_GREATER_EQUAL = r'>='
t_NOT_EQUAL     = r'!='

# Delimiters
t_LPAREN  = r'\('
t_RPAREN  = r'\)'
t_COLON   = r'\:'
t_LBRACE  = r'\{'
t_RBRACE  = r'\}'

# Assignment
t_EQUALS  = r'='


# Rule for identificator
def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
    return t

# Define a rule so we can track line numbers
def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

# Compute column.
#     input is the input text string
#     token is a token instance
def find_column(input, token):
    line_start = input.rfind('\n', 0, token.lexpos) + 1
    return (token.lexpos - line_start) + 1

# A string containing ignored characters (spaces and tabs)
t_ignore  = ' \t'

# Error handling rule
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# One line comments Python alike
def t_comment(t):
    r"[ ]*\043[^\n]*"  # \043 is '#'
    pass

# Build the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

# read input for test purposes
#from read_file_into_buffer import readFileIntoBuffer    
#data = readFileIntoBuffer('test.fpl')
data = input()

# feed lexer with input
lexer.input(data)

# TODO - Create a function to open a file from stdinput
# The file shall be passed as argument


# Tokenize
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok: 
        break      # No more input
    print(tok)
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to be a lexical error and why would you need it to? `NUMBER(123), ID(abc)` is exactly the tokenization I'd expect for that input (in languages without integer suffixes).

Comment: For reference: In Haskell, Ruby and Python `123abc` is tokenized as a number followed by an identifier, just like your code does. In Haskell that's a type error and in Ruby and Python it's a syntax error. In OCaml and C it's tokenized as an integer with the suffix "abc", which leads to an error about `abc` not being a valid integer suffix.